# What are some English words which derrive from the latin "mirrari"?

Tags: verbs

Do there exist English words which derrive from the latin "mirrari"?

Comment: Do you mean *mirari*?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean *mirārī*, with only two R's, then yes. "Admire" and "miracle" are the most prominent.

Comment: It's unclear from the OP, but going based on his other question, I wonder if he might exclude *miracle* since it comes directly from *miracula*, not *mirari*. (I guess technically *admire* comes from a prefixed form, too, but at least it's the same verb.) Maybe he'll clarify what he means.